# Adding onclick to CustomAdapter to handle onClickEvents

Tags: android, listview

Here is my adapter code which currently assigns the values in the DataObject to their respective locations in my layout.xml file. Next, I am trying to add an onclicklistener here which will just print to logcat the only id field that was clicked, rather than the contents of the entire row.

```
private class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataObject> {

    private ArrayList<DataObject> items;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DataObject> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.data_row, null);
        }
        DataObject dataObject = items.get(position);
        if (dataElement != null) {
            TextView field1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.field1);
            TextView  field2= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.field2);
            TextView  id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.field_id);
            if (field1 != null) {
                field1.setText("field1 " + dataOject.getField1);
            }
            if (field2 != null) {
                field2.setText("field2 " + dataOject.getField2);
            }

            view.setClickable(true);
            view.setOnClickListener

            // Would like to simply print the id in this method to Log, so that when a row is clicked, only id is printed



        }


return view;
    }
```

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value from the underlying datastructure which populates the list.
For example if it is populated from a List and you know the position. Just get the corresponding element from the List

For example i used this code in my project

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
         ContactItem contactItem = contactItemList.get(position);
                 ..
            }
 });
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think to do this. Excellent, simple solution, many thanks for your reply!!!

Answer (score 1):

So don't set the `OnClickListener` in your adapter code. In your activity use [setOnListItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29). Using this type of listener will give you the position in the list as one of the arguments. Note the setOnListItemClick is just for the ListActivity, if you're not using a ListActivity, just use [setOnItemClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) on your ListView object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried including an onItemClickListener in the activity but I was only able to get the entire line and could not see a way to get only 1 of the 3 fields (I don't want to parse it out from the line, i'm assuming there is a better way?). I was using this in my onItemClick method to capture the row: Object rowData = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
view.setTag(position);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Clicked = " + position);
       }
});
```

However, I recommend setting `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` on `ListView`, rather than setting individual `OnClickListener` on every item.

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Clicked = " + position);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I wasn't very clear in my above code. I'm actually trying to get the value of a field rather than the list position. My DataObject contains 3 data values which I display in each row, one of those data values is named field_id, this is the value I would like to print on click. TextView  id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.field_id);

Answer (score 0):

You can set the onClickListener in the ListFragment or Activity where you are setting the adapter

```
class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DataAdapter mAdapter = new DataAdapter(..);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            }
        });
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been able to do this in my activity however I can't figure out a way to only select 1 of my 3 fields. Using Object rowData = listView.getItemAtPosition(position) in the onItemClick method I get the entire row of data, what I want is only to get 1 of the 3 fields I setup in my adapter (field_id)